# Unit test for a function with more than one HTTP request

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-httpclient

I have a problem with writing a unit test for a function which indirectly calls more than one HTTP request.

**Service** which is being tested has the following structure:

```
/* content.service.ts */
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"
import { ApiService } from "services/api/api.service"

@Injectable()
export class ContentService {
  public languages: Array<any>
  public categories: Array<any>

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

  public async fetchLanguages(): Promise<boolean> {
    const data: any = await this.apiService.getData("language")

    if (!data) return false

    this.languages = data
    return true
  }

  public async fetchCategories(): Promise<boolean> {
    const data: any = await this.apiService.getData("category")

    if (!data) return false

    this.categories = data
    return true
  }

  public async initService(): Promise<boolean> {
    const statusLanguages: boolean = await this.fetchLanguages()

    if (!statusLanguages) return false

    const statusCategories: boolean = await this.fetchCategories()

    if (!statusCategories) return false

    return true
  }
}
```

Service **test file** looks like this:

```
/* content.service.spec.ts */
import {
  HttpClientTestingModule,
  HttpTestingController
} from "@angular/common/http/testing"
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing"

import { ApiService } from "services/api/api.service"
import { ContentService } from "./content.service"

describe("ContentService:", () => {
  let contentService: ContentService
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      providers: [ ApiService, ContentService ]
    })

    contentService = TestBed.get(ContentService)
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController)
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify()
  })

  /* Dummy data */
  const languages = [
    { id: 1, uid: "en", active: true },
    { id: 2, uid: "es", active: false },
    { id: 3, uid: "hr", active: false }
  ]

  const categories = [
    { id: 1, uid: "default" },
    { id: 2, uid: "alternative" }
  ]

  describe("initService:", () => {
    it("successful response", (done: DoneFn) => {
      contentService.initService().then(result => {
        expect(result).toEqual(true)
        expect(contentService.languages).toEqual(languages)
        expect(contentService.categories).toEqual(categories)
        done()
      })

      const requests = httpMock.match(req => !!req.url.match(/api\/data/))

      expect(requests.length).toBe(2)

      requests[0].flush({ status: "ok", data: languages })
      requests[1].flush({ status: "ok", data: categories })
    })
  })
})
```

When running unit tests with `ng test` following error is being thrown:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'flush' of undefined
```

TypeError is related to the line:

```
requests[1].flush({ status: "ok", data: categories })
```

Which brings me to a conclusion that first request is correctly handled, while the second one is not.

Shouldn't method `match` from the HttpTestingController catch all HTTP requests which match with the provided regular expression?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When writing unit tests you should test only one **unit**. In this case your unit is `ContentService`. Keep in mind that you dont have to test it's dependencies. As I see `ApiService` is a depedency in your service which is used to make **Http Requests**. So You dont have test whether that you are making http requests or not. You just have to mock the ApiService  using a **mock value** or **jasmine spy object**.

```
  const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ApiService', ['getData']);

  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      ContentService,
      { provide: ApiService, useValue: spy }
    ]
  });
```

What you have to test here is the variables inside your `ContentService` are getting the correct values and the return values of the methods according to the input values.

You can test your `ApiService` separately. Do not try to test the dependencies of your classes when you're unit testing.

Comment: This does not answer in any way to the question. Even though what is being said is not necessarily incorrect (I wouldn't say correct 100%).

Comment: @CosminPopescu Could you elaborate why the provided answer is not 100% correct? I'm aware that the answer is not related to the final question of the original post, but it showed another direction on how to successfully test service in the example.